# Code Not working in category description

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

```
<div class="category-description std">
    <p>
  <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var z = jQuery.noConflict();
z("#toglbtn").click(function(){
    z("#catdescr").toggle();
});
// ]]></script>
</p>
<p>Great Discounts .</p>
<p><button id="toglbtn">V</button></p>
<div id="catdescr">
<p>Back to school offer brings printers at just </p>
<p>Laptops at </p>
<p>Routers at </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Button is not toggling the specified Div element, But when I add the below code in Browser, It works fine.

```
var z = jQuery.noConflict();
z("#toglbtn").click(function(){
    z("#catdescr").toggle();
});
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: what error you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="category-description std">
<p>Great Discounts .</p>
<p><button id="toglbtn">V</button></p>
<div id="catdescr">
<p>Back to school offer brings printers at just </p>
<p>Laptops at </p>
<p>Routers at </p>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var z = jQuery.noConflict();
z("#toglbtn").click(function(){
    z("#catdescr").toggle();
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Stephen Do you have any Idea whether Google will index the text inside hidden div element or not?

Comment: You can be penalized for it, if that element is not an action, but the action you there, so you will not be penalized

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="category-description std">
    <p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#toglbtn").click(function(){
            jQuery("#catdescr").toggle();
        });
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>Great Discounts .</p>
    <p><button id="toglbtn">V</button></p>
    <div id="catdescr">
        <p>Back to school offer brings printers at just </p>
        <p>Laptops at </p>
        <p>Routers at </p>
    </div>
</div>
```